# iOS- UIAccessibility focus random table view cell on reloading the table view

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiaccessibility

I have a UITableview, whenever I reload the table view, accessibility focus goes to random cell. I tried to post the notification as below to move the focus to specific cell

```
let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)
let desiredCell = self.myTableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath)
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument:desiredCell)
```

I observed below issue:
**After posting the notification to move the focus to the desired row, focus goes to random row and then it goes to the desired row.**

Anyone faced the same or if you have an idea, please share with me,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facing the same issue here, any updates on this one @jailiani?